# About union of conjugate proper subgroups in a math paper

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

My question is about the shaded area in this image.

[image]

Does the symbol $L=\bigcup_{g \in G} T^{g}$ means that $L$ is a union of sets or $L=\langle T^{g}, g\in G \rangle$? If it means the first one, then how did the authors prove that $L$ equals to that union? If it means the second one, then how did the author conclude that all the elements of order p or 4 (if $p=2$) of $L$ are contained in $K$? I like to add that $L/K$ is an abelian p-group of exponent $p$.

My question comes from the the paper BaoJun Li, ZhiRang Zhang: *The influence of s-conditionally permutable subgroups on finite groups*,  Sci. China Ser. A-Math. (2009) 52: 301; DOI: [10.1007/s11425-009-0028-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11425-009-0028-4)

**If you visited the image link and it did not show up, please click the refresh button.**

Comment: The symbol has the same meaning as in other areas of math: I.e. $L$ (as a set) equals the union of the sets $T^g$. Group theory doesn't redefine this notation.

Comment: @Max: I think some people used the second meaning for that symbole. This link is an example (http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1934-40-12/S0002-9904-1934-05982-2/S0002-9904-1934-05982-2.pdf ). Please see the second paragraph.

Comment: I mean the third paragraph.

Comment: @unknown(google) could you please write down the question? I could not open the file as it is diverted to a site..... Thanks

Comment: @Alireza Abdollahi: I sent the image to your email.

Comment: @unknown (google). Please write down here as a part of your question. In the meanwhile, I have received nothing from your side.

Comment: @Alireza Abdollahi: Please check this link (http://www.scienceforums.net/topic/68456-union-of-subgroups/). I do not know, why you could not receive my email?